# In the E91 protocol, how can Alice and Bob detect Eve if she waits to measure until A&B publish their bases?

Tags: entanglement, key-distribution

I'm studying the E91 protocol. Suppose Eve has a qubit entangled with Alice's and Bob's qubits.

I understand how Alice and Bob can detect Eve if Eve measures before A&B by testing Bell's inequalities.

I'm confused how Alice and Bob could detect Eve if Eve waits to measure her qubit until after A&B publish their bases.

My current understanding: Alice and Bob would measure collapsing the qubits into some state and destorying the entanglement. Eve could then wait until A&B publish their bases and then perfectly recover the secret key by measuring her qubits. And A&B can do nothing to prevent this.

Could someone help me understand what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let us recall the [Ekert-91](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.67.661) (E91) protocol.

- Initially Alice and Bob each independently receive respective elements of a plurality of Bell pairs (for example, generated by [spontaneous parametric down-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion);
- Upon deciding to generate a secret key, Alice and Bob each independently measure their pairs in one of three bases, and publicly announce their bases;
- For the qubit pairs where Alice and Bob measure in the *same* bases, they keep their measurement results secret, as they will be used to generate the key; and
- For the qubit pairs where Alice and Bob measured in *different* bases, they announce publicly their results, so that they can generate statistics inline with the [CHSH game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_game) to test for interference from the eavesdropper Eve.

If I understand your question, you envision Eve:

1. Surreptitiously entangling qubits with either Alice or Bob's;
2. Waiting until Alice and Bob publicly announce each of their bases measurements for each qubit; and then
3. Measuring each of her entangled qubits in the appropriate bases announced by  Alice and Bob.

However, **merely the act of entangling Eve's qubits with those of Alice or Bob destroys the previously available maximal entanglement between Alice and Bob**.

This is the [monogamy of entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy_of_entanglement) - qubits can only be maximally entangled with each other, and not with a third party.  Eve's effort to entangle her qubits with those of Alice/Bob will enable Alice and Bob to run the Bell tests on their qubits, to detect this corruption.

I also think the [principle of deferred measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Measurement_Principle) may be at play - it should not matter whether Eve measures before or after Alice and Bob contemporaneously announce their bases. If it did, then Eve could send a superluminal message to either Alice or Bob(!)  For example, if there is a difference between measuring before or after Alice and Bob communicating, then Eve could turn this around to send a bit to Alice and Bob without actually sending any classical information to either Alice or Bob.  This violates the [no-signaling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem).